# Send files to Android Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm developing a simple RSS app for Android Wear.  I'd like to give the user an option to import an OPML file, but I'm having trouble finding any support on sending files to watch and/or reading the file system of the watch.

With AW 2.0 Google seems to be pushing for apps that run on the watch only but I'm guessing for this, I'd have to build a companion phone app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need a companion phone app to do this. To transfer the file, most likely you'll want to pass it as an `Asset`, documented here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/assets.html

Accessing the filesystem on Wear is the same as on any other Android device. For this use case, you'll probably want to use your app's default, private internal  storage location. The documentation for doing so is here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal